# RoR3: ajax form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in **RoR2** we may use:

```
remote_form_for "something", :update => {:success => "smthId", :failure => "errors"} do |f|
```

to make an ajax request and rerender a correspondent div or whatever with `smthId`;

---

In **RoR3** `remote_form_for` is deprecated , so :

```
form_for @something, :remote => true do |f|
```

has to be used.

---

My question:
 Is there an option like `:update => {}` for `form_for` helper in **RoR3** or javascript's method should be triggered in controller for everytime `smthId` needs to be rerendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **update option** in rails 3. 
You can use it like below:

```
 $("#new_something").bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status){});
 $("#new_something").bind('ajax:error', function(xhr, data, status){});
```